# How to remove duplicate records from multiple lists in order in python

Tags: python

I have three list with four values in each list, I have to remove duplicate values from these three list

Here are three lists

```
country_list = ['USA', 'India', 'China', 'India']
city_list = ['New York', 'New Delhi', 'Beijing', 'New Delhi']
event_list = ['First Event', 'Second Event', 'Third Event', 'Second Event']
```

As its showing in all three lists "India", "new delhi", and Second event" are repeating, means they again are repeating with each other. I want to remove these repeating value, and wants the result like

```
country_list = ['USA', 'India', 'China']
city_list = ['New York', 'New Delhi', 'Beijing']
event_list = ['First Event', 'Second Event', 'Third Event']
```

So how can i get this result is there any function for this ?

Comment: What does this have to do with django?

Answer (score 3):

One simple way is to do the following:

```
country_list = list(set(country_list))
city_list = list(set(city_list))
event_list = list(set(event_list))
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
country_list = list(set(country_list))
city_list = list(set(city_list))
event_list = list(set(event_list))
```

Ought to do it. This is because a [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) cannot have duplicates by definition. When you convert your list to a set, the duplicates are discarded. If you want the data to be in a form of a list once again you need to convert it back to a list as shown above. In most cases you can use the set exactly as you would use a list.

for example

```
for item in set(country_list):
    print item
```

so the conversion back to list may not be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `set()`. 
Have a look into this: [Python Sets](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/set)

And this:[Sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html)

For your Lists you can do it like this:

`>>> city_list = ['New York', 'New Delhi', 'Beijing', 'New Delhi']`

`>>> set(city_list)`

`set(['New Delhi', 'New York', 'Beijing'])`

`>>> list(set(city_list))`

`['New Delhi', 'New York', 'Beijing']`